# How to use map in Julia to mimic a nested list comprehension?

Tags: julia, list-comprehension

I would like to use Julia's `map` function to mimic a nested list comprehension. This ability would be particularly useful for parallel mapping (`pmap`).

For example, this nested list comprehension

```
[x+y for x in [0,10] for y in [1,2,3]]
```

produces the nice result

```
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
 11
 12
 13
```

and this

```
[x+y for x in [0,10], y in [1,2,3]]
```

produces the equally nice

```
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
 11  12  13
```

Either of these outcomes are satisfactory for my purposes.

Now here is my best effort at replicating these outcomes with `map`

```
map([0,10]) do x
    map([1,2,3]) do y
        x + y
    end
end
```

which yields the correct results, just not in a form I admire:

```
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]   
 [11, 12, 13]
```

Now I know there are brute-force ways get the outcome I want, such as `hcat`/`vcat`'ing  the output or manipulating the input into a matrix, but I'd like to know if there exists a solution as elegant as the nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use comprehensions and combine them with `map` (low benefit) or `pmap` (here you get the real value).

On Julia 0.7 (use the fact that in this release you have destructuring in function arguments functionality):

```
julia> map(((x,y) for x in [0,10] for y in [1,2,3])) do (x,y)
       x+y
       end
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
 11
 12
 13

julia> map(((x,y) for x in [0,10], y in [1,2,3])) do (x,y)
       x+y
       end
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
 11  12  13
```

On Julia 0.6.2 (less nice):

```
julia> map(((x,y) for x in [0,10] for y in [1,2,3])) do v
              v[1]+v[2]
              end
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
 11
 12
 13

julia> map(((x,y) for x in [0,10], y in [1,2,3])) do v
              v[1]+v[2]
              end
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
 11  12  13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Iterators.product`:

```
julia> map(t -> t[1]+t[2], Iterators.product([0,10], [1,2,3]))
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
 11  12  13
```

`Iterators.product` returns an iterator whose elements are tuples.

(It's a shame the anonymous function above couldn't be written `(x,y) -> x+y`)